# Would a "hub" page work better as a page or a post?

Tags: posts, pages, tags

First of all, I don't know whether "hub" is the correct terminology, but it is how we've been describing it. I run a movie blog and would like to create a page for each movie we cover in depth. I want it to be more than just a tage archive, so I'm wondering how to get it done.

For instance, [What Culture](http://whatculture.com/movie/captain-america-the-winter-soldier-2014) employs a similar system. In the example link, there is a blurb about the movie and all related articles to that movie.

If I were to do something in the same vain, should this be done via a page or a post?

Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For things like that a page is better option, because you can make use of [custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and also because pages are a better place for inner secondary queries.

As example, if you want to use pagination for secondary queries, alongside `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()`, both those functions check `if ( ! is_single() )` to display pagination and `is_single()` is true if you use a post, but is false if you use a page, so they will not work inside a single post but will inside a page.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My only argument against using pages for this purpose is that the number can add up quite quickly (every time a new movie comes out). Isn't it desirable to keep the number of pages to a minimum?

Comment: @banjax Why it should be desiderable? Which is the benefit of having a lot of posts instead of a lot of pages?

Comment: I probably don't have the most accurate conventional wisdom working behind me, but I always viewed pages as static containers that cannot be classified. Like obviously a contact and about page would be a page. But if I am adding an ever-growing wave of pages for each new movie we cover, then it just feels post-like.

Comment: furthermore, if I wanted to do the same for coverage of tv shows, can you classify pages by category? Like, these pages are all "movies" and these pages are all "tv shows".

Comment: In WordPress page and post are pretty same things internally. And yes, if you want you can have taxonomy for pages. @banjax